# Full height to div with relative position

Tags: css

How can I assign full height to a div with relative position -

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home-gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.rc-contain {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.rc-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-gallery">
  <div class="rc-contain">
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="rc-slider">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

but my home-gallery div is not taking full height. How can I assign height dynamically to home-gallery as I am focusing on responsive design.

Comment: It is 100% height, no? Can u show the result you want to acquire and what result u are getting from the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add following line to css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="home-gallery">
    <div class="rc-contain">
       ....contain
    </div>
    <div class="rc-slider">
       ....slider
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.home-gallery{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid;
}

.rc-contain{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.rc-slider{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

here is jsfiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fLbL05vd/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your code but somehow it is not working for me. Can you please help me out. The link is - http://www.planetradiocity.com/home.php. Check on mobile. The slider and content is overlapping.

Comment: slider and content is overlapping because you have define same position for both

Comment: may I know why "home-galleryDiv" div is not taking its full height if I assign it 100% ?

Comment: give height in "px". and it will work, without html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: when you give height in %, but % of what..? so its parent have to some height.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.home-gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.rc-contain {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
  /* red */
}
.rc-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  /* blue */
}
```

```html
<div class="home-gallery">
  <div class="rc-contain">
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="rc-slider">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set HTML Body full width

```
 html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

After that, you can set your div with the relative position to take full width and height

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/5591663/pexels-photo-5591663.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

**Final result:**

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/XWKYEYb?editors=0100

[image]